# After uninstalling Ubuntu 12.04, only grub rescue is loading, can't get into BIOS

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I had a dual booting system with win 8 and Ubuntu 12.04. I deleted Ubuntu using windows disk management, created a win 8 recovery USB disk to repair MBR and rebooted. The system went into grub rescue. I am not able to go into BIOS at all (pressing F2 no response). Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

A: Was a BIOS setting changed? (ie fastboot enabled)

B: Did the system come with windows 8?

If B was true:

- Completely power off
- Hold f2
- Power on (still holding f2)

Did your motherboard start beeping?  If so, then you have some funky BIOS settings enabled.  Your boot mode might be set to CSM when trying to access windows 8, which might have been installed in UEFI mode.

I had both of these problems.  If fast-boot is enabled, it gets a lot harder to access BIOS.  You might have to do a CMOS reset.  This just means, take out CMOS battery, leave it out for bout an hour, put it back in, tada.

You can also try pulling out your hard drive.  Then you should boot right to the BIOS, assuming you don't have a bootable USB/LAN/ODD device plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by removing the battery, waiting for 5 minutes and then reinserting it. I then switched the laptop on (only on battery, not on external power supply) and voila - I was able to select BIOS by pressing F2

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I'd make sure you still have a Windows partition. You can check this by entering

```
ls
```

At grub rescue. You should have at least one partition called MSDOS(1) or something of the like. If you don't have that, chances are you cooked your hard drive and need a clean install.

Assuming it's still there, you definitely need to get into the BIOS as it sounds like it's set to boot from HDD rather than USB first. To get into the BIOS, I'll assume that <kbd>F2</kbd> is the correct key. You need to press this before the GrUB is loaded. Once GrUB is up, it's kind of like you're in a mini OS, it's too late to get into the BIOS, you need to reboot and try again.